# dev tools sources doesn't appear installed packages so this causes an error

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, node-modules, openid-client-js

I have such a situation: I've installed some packages in my NextJS project. But dev tools `source` tab doesn't appear the full package. And this causes an error. Here is an example:

In my project I have the next structure:
[image]

But in the devtools the following:

[image]